# django, Changing field values ​in model before saving to database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

class PlayerList(models.Model):

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
position = models.CharField(max_length=200)
h_code = models.ForeignKey(HList, related_name="h_code", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
d_code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length = 200, editable=False)
```

Serializers.py

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        fields = ["name", "position", "h_code", "d_code"]
        model = PlayerList
```

view.py

```
class PostPlayer(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = PlayerList.objects.all().order_by('-d_code')
    serializer_class = PlayerListSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        d_code = request.data.get('h_code') + 'test'
        print(d_code)
```

print(d_code) :

```
h000001test
```

When entering a value through api, I want to implement that the entered value is changed to another value in view.py and saved in the db.

I want to save d_code processed by def get in db.

I don't know what to do. Can you please let me know?

There is no answer, so I will post again.

Comment: If you want to update the object, then use an uodate api view. Get method is used for only showing the data. When you use the corresponding updateapiview, you can override the update method to process the argument and update the model object accordinly. Let know if that solves your problem.

Comment: I know how to change the data, but I don't know how to put the changed data into a model field. Did you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override your views `perform_create()` method, as stated in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods) (you might have to scroll a little, its in the *Save and deletion hooks* section:

```py
class PostPlayer(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = PlayerList.objects.all().order_by('-d_code')
    serializer_class = PlayerListSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        d_code = request.data.get('h_code') + 'test'
        print(d_code)
    ...
    ...
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        d_code = request.data.get('h_code') + 'test'
        #do something with d_code
        new_code = d_code + 'someSampleValue'
        serializer.save(d_code=new_code)
```